# How to pass the 'callbacks' array argument to an anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

I have a member function in the object which gets the array of callback functions and the name of the event for which this function is set:

```
...
setHandlesByList: function (list) {
    for (var i in list) {
        var self = this;
        $(document).on(list[i].name, function (e) {
            list[i].callBack.call(self,e)
        });
    };
},
...
```

Somewhere in the child objects I have a call to this function of the parent object:

```
...
initClass: function () {
    this.setHandlesByList([
     { name: 'configChecked', callBack: onConfigChecked },
     { name: 'configExpired', callBack: onConfigExpired },
    ]);
},
onConfigChecked: function() {
    // some code
},
onConfigExpired: function() {
    // some code
},
....
```

but something goes wrong - for all events the handler is the last set callback function...

Comment: **Wow** is that indentation hard to read.

Comment: You can infact try `$(document).on(list[i].name,list[i].callBack.bind(this))` or use a closure because you have a shared variable `i` with your current impl.

Comment: @PSL, `$.proxy` is jQuery's backwards compatible implementation of `Function.prototype.bind`, and it has some additional features that are useful for event bindings.

Comment: i've tried something like:
for (var i in list) {
    var self = this,
        mn = list[i].name,
        cb = list[i].callBack;
        $(document).on( nm, function (e) { cb.call(self,e) });
};

but it also odon't work as wanted...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each event handler function you create in this code:

```
setHandlesByList: function (list) {
    for (var i in list) {
    var self = this;
    $(document).on(list[i].name, function (e) {
        list[i].callBack.call(self,e)
        });
    };
},
```

...has an **enduring reference** to `list` and `i`, not *copies* of them as of when the function is created. Since `i` ends up being the last property enumerated, all handlers end up referring to the same list entry.

Instead, create a builder function to create the callback *(sorry, I can't recreate the indentation style you use, I've just used a fairly standard one)*:

```
setHandlesByList: function (list) {
    var self = this;

    for (var i in list) {
        $(document).on(list[i].name, buildHandler(list[i]));
    };

    function buildHandler(entry) {
        return function (e) {
            entry.callBack.call(self,e)
        };
    }
},
```

Now, the function created closes over `entry`, the argument to the `buildHandler` call, rather than over `list` and `i`. Since `entry` (the argument) doesn't change, the handler works.

Note also that I've moved the `var self = this;` out of the loop, as it didn't vary from iteration to iteration and so had no business being in the loop.

---

Side note: You've said that the function receives an **array**. If so, `for-in` (with no safeguards) is not the correct way to loop through the entries in that array. More: [*Myths and realities of `for..in`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/11/myths-and-realities-of-forin.html)

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
setHandlesByList: function (list) {
    for ( var i = 0; i < list.length; i++ ) {
        addCallback(list[i].name, list[i].callback);
    }
    function addCallback(on, name, callback) {
        $(document).on(name, function(e) { callback.call(on, e); });
    }
},
```

There is a problem with your scoping, because the value of `i` eventually ends up being the last value of `i` when your callbacks are evaluated.

Also note that you could use `list.forEach`.